# Querying mongodb keeping the order, using the $in operator

Tags: mongodb, batch-processing

I have a list of urls (resources), and a list of views for each resource, all of them are 
stored into a mongodb database. In other words, a `resource` has many associated `views`.

Both resources and views contain a field `url`, which I'm using to identify the website the resource and the view is about.

I have a list of urls in a var `urls`, and I want to return, for each of them, **in the same order urls are**, **only one of the views** that is associated with this url.

So there is two criterion that are interesting for me:

- Query using the $in operator, keeping the order of the results regarding the list I passed.
- Only returning one item for each key in the $in list.

Of course, I can iterate in my code and do something like this (in python):

```
views = []
for url in urls:
    views.append(db.views.find_one({"url": url}))
```

I don't know how the `$in` operator exactly behaves and if it can solve my problem, but I'm afraid it will not keep the order I'm interested in. Maybe can I sort the results after querying?

But this means making N queries for N urls which doesn't seems optimized at all. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible. There is no order guarantee for $in (verify with `db.test.save({a:1}); db.test.save({a:2}); db.test.find({a:{$in:[2,1]}})` ) and currently you can only sort on fields and not fixed ordered sets of values.